# MP3 issue with HTML5 <audio> in Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, audio, mp3

I'm a little bit confused about the `<audio>` tag and the mp3 file support in firefox. I red several articles and Q&A here, which said that the mp3 format is supported since Firefox 21. But if I load per SoundCloud SDK some samples files and initialize them with the `<audio>` tag. But only in Chrome it works.
Opera doesn't understand the `AudioContext()`.
Firefox doesn't support the file format as well as the `MediaElementSource` for non-local sources.
MS...well...it's MS.

Is that a bug or did I code something wrong for compatibility?

I use **Firefox 31** -- Status-Code for mp3 file:   HTTP/1.1 206 Partial Content
Accept: audio/webm,audio/ogg,audio/wav,audio/*;q=0.9,application/ogg;q=0.7,video/*;q=0.6,*/*;q=0.5

---

** UPDATE - 26.08.2014 **
I tried to load the mp3s via CORS but all browsers response with `Content type 'application/json' not supported`
*Code-Snippet for that:*

```
var url = 'https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks.json?client_id=YOUR_CLIENT_ID';
$.getJSON(url, function(tracks) {
  $(tracks).each(function(i, track) {
    var audio = new Audio();
    audio.src = 'https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks.json?url=' + track.uri + '&client_id=YOUR_CLIENT_ID';
    audio.controls = true;
    document.getElementById('audio_box').appendChild(audio)
  });
});
```

---

** UPDATE - 26.08.2014 **
Successfully loaded the files with `CORS` but with the `createAudioBuffer` instead of `MediaElementSource`. Until now there are no relevant quality reduction. I'm worried about artefacts, because the AudioBuffer isn't construct for 3-5 minute tracks. Rather small sound files like noises. Now I have some troubles to connect all files with the analyser. Only if I set `audioSource[i].start();` the first loaded audio file will go through the analyser. I want that every audio file will go trough that analyser if I press the play button on the `<audio>` tag. I hope I figured out soon.

*Code-Snippet for that:*

```
        trackSource = track.uri + '/stream?client_id=YOUR_CLIENT_ID';
        audio.src = trackSource;
        audio.controls = true;
        audio.loop = false;
        audio.autoplay = false;
        audio.preload = "none";
        audio.setAttribute('data-tracknumber', i+1);

        d.getElementById('audio_box').appendChild(audio);

        analyser.connect(audioCtx.destination);

        fetchAudioAsset(trackSource, audioCtx, function( buffer ) {
          audioSource = [];
          audioSource[i] = audioCtx.createBufferSource();
          audioSource[i].buffer = buffer;
          audioSource[i].connect(audioCtx.destination);
          audioSource[i].connect(analyser);
          audioSource[i].start();
        });

        function fetchAudioAsset (path, audioCtx, callback) {
            invocation.open('GET', path, true);
            invocation.responseType = 'arraybuffer';
            invocation.onload = function() {
                if (invocation.readyState != 4) return;
                audioCtx.decodeAudioData(invocation.response, function(buffer) {
                    callback && callback(buffer);
                });
            }.bind(this);
            invocation.onprogress = function(ev) {
              $('.loaded').width(((ev.loaded / ev.total) * 100) + '%');
            };

          fetchAudioAsset.request && fetchAudioAsset.request.abort();
          fetchAudioAsset.request = invocation;
          invocation.send();
        };
```

---

Here is some code:
**Javascript**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    var source, context, analyser;
    context = new AudioContext();
    analyser = context.createAnalyser();
    analyser.connect(context.destination);

    function waveform(i, track){    
        var     d = document,
                w = d.createElement('div'),
                c = d.createElement('div'),
                p = d.createElement('button'),
            audio = new Audio();

        audio.src = track.uri + '/stream?client_id=YOUR_CLIENT_ID';
        audio.controls = true;
        audio.loop = false;
        audio.autoplay = false;
        audio.preload = "none";
        audio.setAttribute('data-tracknumber', i + 1);

        $('<div class="audioWrapper"><div class="url"></div><img class="img" /><div class="controls"><button class="play-pause"></button></div></div>').appendTo('#audio_box').append(audio);
        tracks = [];   
        tracks[i] = context.createMediaElementSource(audio);
        tracks[i].connect(analyser);
    }

    var set_url = "https://soundcloud.com/kindisch-1/sets/favoriten";
    SC.get('/resolve', {
        url: set_url
    }, function (set) {
        i = 0;
        $(set.tracks).each(function (i, track) {
            waveform(i, track);
        });
    });
});
```

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="//connect.soundcloud.com/sdk.js"></script>
<script src="js/functions.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">
div#mp3_player{ width:500px; background:#000; padding:5px; margin:50px auto; }
div#mp3_player > div > audio{  width:500px; background:#000; float:left;  }
div#mp3_player > canvas{ width:500px; height:30px; background:#002D3C; float:left; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="mp3_player">
        <div id="audio_box"> </div>
        <canvas id="analyser_render"> </canvas>
    </div>
    <div id="tracks"> </div>
    <div>
        <button class="play-pause">Play</button>
        <input id="volumn" type="range" name="volumn" min="0.0" max="1.0" step="0.01"><label for="volumn">Volumn</label>
    </div> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: last i checked (last year), FF supported MP3 only in windows, not sure if that's still true.

Comment: Yes, thats right. Windows 7, Windows 8, Windows Vista, and Android now supports MP3.

I'm using Windows 8.1